# Confidential interval for ratio of mathematical expectations

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

I've got 2 sequences of Bernoulli random variables: ${X_1, ... , X_n}$ and ${Y_1, ... , Y_n}$
For each mathematical expectations ($EX$ and $EY$) of these sequences i can find confidence intervals.
But now it is necessary to find confidence interval for ratio of this expectations $\frac{EX}{EY}$.
Is there any ways to find it using confidence interval of $EX$ and $EY$?

Comment: Is there any way to find confidence interval for any combination of  two mathematical expectations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If some parameter $u$ is in the interval $(x-a,x+a)$ with probability at least $1-p$ and if some parameter $v$ is in the interval $(y-b,y+b)$ with probability at least $1-q$ then each $K(u,v)$ is in the set $\{K(x+ta,y+sb)\mid -1\lt t,s\lt1\}$ with probability at least $1-(p+q)$.

In your case, $u=E(X)$, $v=E(Y)$ and $K(\xi,\eta)=\xi/\eta$ hence $x$ and $y$ are positive and, for every $a\lt x$ and $b\lt y$, $S_K$ is the interval $(z,w)$ with $z=(x-a)/(y+b)$ and $w=(x+a)/(y-b)$. The half-length of the interval $S_K$ is $c=(bx+ay)/(y^2-b^2)$, hence, if $b\ll y$, $c\sim(bx+ay)/y^2$. Since $y$ is supposed to estimate $v$, what all this says is that the quality of the combined estimator $x/y$ to estimate the unknown quantity $u/v$ is low if $v$ is small.

Comment: i think about the similar solution but i didn't know if it is right. So, if our thoughts are similar i think that it is really so.     
And for any combination it is clear how to find confedence interval.